# Find two matrices such that the sum of their ranks is the rank of the sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Find $2$ non-zero, $2 \times 2$ matrices, such that $\mathrm{rank}(A+B)=\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B)$

I want to start from the identity matrix and work backwards, but I cant seem to cook up two matrices.

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}? & ? \\ ? & ? \end{pmatrix}$